# Phanton lines in a PostGIS ST_Union

Tags: postgis, union

I created a polygon using ST_UNION. However, it shows some lines inside that don't make sense, as you can see below.

How can I create the union poly without those lines or remove it from the poly created?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps they are not lines but narrow polygons or holes. Could you zoom closer and have a look?

Answer (score 1):

As another answer noted, these are almost certainly narrow holes caused by the input polygons not being totally node-matched.  Ideally you would fix the input to match all nodes.  But to fix the output you can simply drop the holes from the result polygon:

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(geom)) AS geom
FROM <query for polygon>
```

Note: this assumes there are no "real" holes in the output.  If there are, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this merging our elementary school boundaries into their corresponding middle/high boundaries. Gaps and slivers in the contributing elementary polygons shows up in the middle/high boundaries as the same phantom lines. My advice would be to clean up the input polygons where those lines are showing up and attempt the merge again until you get it clean.

Manually speaking, you should use the phantom lines as a guide to zoom way in on your input polygons to see what is going on there. Otherwise, the topology checker tool/plugin in QGIS will help too. Topological editing in QGIS to fill the gaps might be the best way to fix them.